# How can I re-size and re-position a shadowbox/greybox window to display in a certain div element?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I would like to know if it is possible to re-size and re-position a greybox or shadowbox window to display in a certain div element?

I am creating a template for a wordpress site, and I am using the default calendar, but when you click on a date inside of the calendar, the default action is to open it up in a new window.

Would it be possible to mod greybox or shadowbox in such a way that when you click on a date, the box opens up over the calendar displaying the contents in it, instead of a new page?

Or is there another way of achieving the desired result, maybe with jQuery or Javascript?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) has a widget called [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) that can achieve your result. You could use it like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    // This will initialize the dialog box and hide it by default.
    // You can find a list of most options here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal : true,
    });

    // This will select the links like you specified
    $('#wp-calendar a').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault() // Disable the link from going to a new page
        var url = $(this).attr("href"); // Pull the HRef for the link for making the AJAX request

        // This will make an AJAX request and put the result in the dialog.
        $("#dialog").empty().load(url, function() {

            // This is the callback for when the AJAX request finishes
            // All it does it open the dialog, which now has data in it
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });
});
```

Note: You'd need to install [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) for this, and you'll probably want to read up on Dialog [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). You'll need to take more steps if you'd want this to degrade gracefully, and depending on your markup. If you could post a snippet of a "day" on the calendar, I can try to tailor it to your needs.

---

Edit: Lets say that the file that return the rendered page for the event is "/ajax/event.php?id=123", you'd first want to prevent the link's default behavior (of navigating to a new page); then you'd want to use jQuery's load function to load an assembled URL's data into the dialog; once that request completes, you'd want to open the dialog. I've edited to code to do so, and it will degrade gracefully for user that don't have JavaScript enabled.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give it a go, thanx! 
I'll report back asap.

Comment: You'll need to take some more steps to make it work with your code, specifically. Just post a snippet of the "day" in the calendar that triggers this and I'll see if I can help with that. I've added some comments to the script, also.

Comment: I have managed to assign a class to all the link tags in the wordpress calendar, using this jquery code, 

$(function() {
   $('#wp-calendar').find('a').each( function() {
       $(this).addClass( 'testing' );
   });
});

Is there a way to apply the jquery dialog, to open all of the links that have that class in a dialog box?

Comment: I've updated the answer, if you can find all the `<a>`'s like that, then you can just apply the click event handler to them immediately. Also `$("#wp-calendar a") should select them all just fine. If you want the Dialog to be resizable or specify the size manually, check out the options that can be passed the a jQuery dialog, I've added a link to the page with all of them in the comments.

Comment: Awesome, thanx a million! I'll keep you posted on my progress.

Comment: It works ok in FF but it freaks out in IE, it seems to be in a endless loop.

I can see the scroll-bar getting smaller, but nothing displays.

Comment: Ok, now it's freaking out in FF as well, when I open a window and close it the first time, it's ok, but when I open another one, it opens the previous one below that one as well.

The calendar is in jquery tabs at the moment, I am assuming that could be a problem?

Comment: Ah, it looks like it's appending the data to the dialog, I've updated the answer to empty the dialog before loading the data into it.

Comment: Still seems a bit buggy, when I open it up once, it works ok, but as soon as I open it up again, it loads twice, and if I open it up a third time, 3 or more windows pop up over each other.

Thanx so much for the help, much appreciated.